# How to repeatedly sort element in div without losing clickability?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example of what I need:

http://jsfiddle.net/bbGMB/1/

```
var interval = 100;
$(function(){
    $('#container').children().click(function(e){
        alert($(e.target).text()+" clicked");
    });
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#container').children().sort(function(a,b){
            if($(a).text() > $(b).text()) return 1;
            if($(a).text() < $(b).text()) return -1;
            return 0;
        }).appendTo('#container');
    },interval);
})
```

If we change interval to 10000 everything works fine.

But I need  interval about 100 or lower.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Your fiddle seems to work fine?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just sort when your container changes (i.e. when you add children or change their value)?

Comment: @pixelcdv
It changes every 16 millisecond.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan
I'm testing it in chrome. Try to lower interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified your fiddle to compare. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/bbGMB/4/

```
var interval = 100;
$(function(){
    $('#container').children().click(function(e){
        alert($(e.target).text()+" clicked");
    });
    setInterval(function(){
        var origC = $('#container').children(); 
        var newC  = $.extend([], origC);

            newC.sort(function(a,b) {
            if($(a).text() > $(b).text()) return 1;
            if($(a).text() < $(b).text()) return -1;
            return 0;
        });
        for (var i=0; i < origC.length; i++) {
            if (origC[i] !== newC[i]) {
                newC.appendTo('#container');
                break;
            }
        }

    },interval);
})
```

Comment: It will work in the fiddle since the numbers don't change, but if the container's children change every 16ms as @ROMB said it will very probably have the same result

Comment: Basically DOM getting modified only when the elements have changed.

Comment: @closure yeah I see that but is the issue therefore caused by the element being replaced with itself before the click even has a chance to fire?

Comment: Based on @pixelcdv 's comment I would change the `.click()` binding to a `.on('click')` on the `#container` to catch any new items

Comment: I think the better model is to activate time based sorter outside the event. Or even better model would be to call the sorter when required and not using timer at all.

Comment: In my task sorting is made not by value, but by some data assigned to elements. Data changes every 16 milliseconds but order may be not changed. Because of this solution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue correctly, you don't have to sort repeatedly at certain intervals. Just call the sort-function when the element gets clicked. (where your current call to alert() is)